# Azure ML Studio - How to score new data with trained model?

Tags: azure, machine-learning, prediction

I have an Azure ML Studio experiment which successfully trains a model and outputs the Scored Probabilities across each observation.

I need a way to reuse the trained model and score new data within a new experiment.
I couldn't find any material on this and the closest I can see is creating a Web Service.

Any assistance or clues would be greatly appreciated.
Again - what I want to do is have a new data-set and have it scored (logistic regression) according to the trained model.

Answer (score 1):

1. Set up Web Service
2. Deploy Web Service which publishes Trained Model
3. Create new experiment and insert 'Load Trained Model' module
4. Link to HTTP URL
5. Connect up Import Data module and Score Model Modules